# Как сделать, чтобы в таблице excel автоматически подстраивалась ширина колонки под длину ее содержимого?

Tags: python, pandas

То есть я сохраняю DataFrame с помощью метода `.to_excel('document'xlsx')`. Потом я открываю этот файл и вижу, что ширина одной из колонок слишком мала, чтобы показать всю информацию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вручную увеличить ширину этой колонке то будет информация будет видна полностью.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу увеличить ширину программно?

Comment: Скорее всего не средствами Pandas. Не думаю, что там средства форматирования экселя поддерживаются. Хотя могу и ошибаться.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно использовать

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'D:\\файл.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Название листа', index=False)
worksheet = writer.sheets['Название листа']
worksheet.set_column('A:D', 20)# Задаем ширину колонок с А по D 
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Не рекомендую этот способ. Вот что пишет разработчик:   FutureWarning: save is not part of the public API, usage can give unexpected results and will be removed in a future version
  writer.save()